# $cos(ax)=a\cdot cos(x)$ Which are all the values of $a$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How do I know for which values of $a$ is true the following?$\space$

$cos(ax)=a\cdot cos(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

---

It is trivial that it is true for $a=1$. But are the more values of $a$ for which it is true?

Comment: There are no other values $a \in \Bbb R$ for which this holds

Comment: And how can I prove it? @BenGrossmann

Comment: True for **all** $x\in\mathbb R$? Then substitute $x=0$.

Comment: True for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ @drhab

Comment: Then also for $x=0$ and substituting that we find that $1=a$.

Comment: The [implicit plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=cos%28y+x%29%3Dy+cos%28x%29) shows $a=1$ is not the only value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing with $x=0$ gives $1 = a$, so $a=1$ is the only value.

Answer (score 1):

By no means a real proof, but if you series-expand teach trig term and re-combine powers in $x$, it's pretty clear:

\begin{align*}\cos\left(ax\right) &= a \cos x \\ 1 - \frac{a^2x^2}{2!} + \frac{a^4x^4}{4!} - \cdots &= a - a\frac{x^2}{2!} + a\frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots \\ \left(1-a\right) - \frac{x^2}{2!}\left(a^2-a\right) + \frac{x^4}{4!}\left(a^4 - a\right) - \cdots&= 0\end{align*}

For the above to hold for any $x$, the terms in parentheses must each be zero. This only works with $a=1$.

Comment: I think your argument is perfectly fine since Taylor series expansion is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If $|a|>1$, then $|a\cos(x)|=|a|>1$ for some values of $x$, but you never have $|\cos(ax)|>1$. So, it's not true then that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\cos(ax)=a\cos(x).\tag1$$And, if $|a|<1$, you never have $a\cos(x)=1$, but $\cos(ax)=1$ for some value of $x$. So, gain, it's not true that you have $(1)$.

On the other hand, if $a=-1$, it's clear that you also don't have $(1)$. So, the only solution is $a=1$.